# WSA Error:10022 while using recvfrom(), winsock Windows Socket Programming

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, winsock

I am trying to learn socket programming on windows. I've learnt socket programming in good detail on a Linux system.
I understand that the libraries and header files are different on windows.
From what I understand we need to initialize windows socket API, create a raw socket and then use it(I might be wrong). However, I'm getting error 10022, which indicates invalid arguments, while trying to receive data. Since I'm using a raw socket, I don't think I need to bind it.

I've written this to straight forward code which is encountering the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ws2tcpip.h"
#include <sys/types.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Winsock Initialized\n");

    printf("Creating Raw socket\n");
    int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    if(sock_fd == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d\n" , WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    printf("Setting socket to raw mode.\n");
    int optval;
    optval = 1;
    if(setsockopt(sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&optval, sizeof(optval))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Failed to set socket in raw mode.");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Socket set to raw mode.\n");


    SOCKADDR_STORAGE saddr;
    int saddr_len;

    char buffer[1024];
    int size_recv = recvfrom(sock_fd,buffer,1024,0,(SOCKADDR *)&saddr, &saddr_len);
    if(size_recv == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not recv data : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    

    closesocket(sock_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Please someone point out what I'm doing wrong here. Also, if anyone knows, is there any header file like "ip.h" for structures of IP header, UDP header etc./
Thank you.

Comment: recvfrom expects a bound socket

Comment: Also, `saddr_len` needs to be initialized to the byte size of `saddr` before passing it to `recvfrom()`